# How to remove trailing slash by using nginx ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I want to configure my ingress.yaml to remove the trailing slash from the path for each route.

For example,

`example.com/` should be redirected to `example.com`

`example.com/my-path/` should be redirected to `example.com/my-path`

How to do that?

Here is my ingress.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: example-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex` and `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotations. Try this:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /(.+)/+$
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: example-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Let me know if it is working.

Comment: Here is the error I get: The Ingress "example-ingress" is invalid: spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].path: Invalid value: "^/(.+)/+$": must be an absolute path

Comment: Would you please try again?
removed `^` and `$`

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: @SüleymanGezsat I applied this to verify and did not get an error. My cluster is a minikube with the nginx ingress controller